# TypeScript cannot infer type in subclass method

Tags: typescript, tslint, tsc

So I have this TS class:

```
export abstract class CPComponent<
  P,
  S = RootState
> extends React.Component<P, S> {

  cpComponentDidCatch?(p: P, s?: S, t?: this): void;


  constructor(p: P, s: any) {
    super(p, s);
  }

  abstract cpRender(p: P, s: S, t?: this): ReactElement;

  componentDidCatch() {
    return (
      this.cpComponentDidCatch &&
      this.cpComponentDidCatch(this.props, this.state, this)
    );
  }


  render() {
    return this.cpRender(this.props, this.state, this);
  }
}
```

and then I subclass it with:

```
type State = {car: string};
type Props = {bug: string}

export class Foo extends CPComponent<Props,State> { // {bug: any},{car: any}

  cpComponentDidCatch(p){

  }

  cpRender(){
    return (
      <div>
        rendered
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

but the problem is I am getting a compile error:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

shouldn't TS know that the type of `p` is `P`?

// it wants me to add more text so here we go

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#1373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373) (possibly succeeded by [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082)) and the abandoned [microsoft/TypeScript#6118](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118) and [despair](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207)

Comment: damn that sux, seems like a useful feature that's AWOL